# Cast function + DRM

Tags: google-contacts-api

I have a question regarding combination of Google Cast + DRM Streaming.

What we have:
Google Cast “Sender App” feature inside our mobile app that sends stream to TV
without implementing a “Receiver App” logic inside our TV app, because we want to use default Cast logic.

It works for open streams (without DRM).
**And doesn’t work for DRM Streams.**

Looks like we cannot implement simple “Sender App” for DRM Streams.
Documentation reference:
"However, if you would like to Cast DRM protected content, you should build and host your own Web Receiver" from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/exoplayer

Question:
Are there any successfull examples of Cast implementation among without a custom “Receiver App”?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, I implemented the casting feature using the exoplayer cast extension. There isn't so much documentation on it but the exoplayer github repo helped me implement it. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/cast